# What happened to Aham and its derivatives in Marathi?

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, sanskrit, indo-aryan

The Sanskrit first person pronoun **अहम् (Romanized: Aham)** can be found in **Maharashtri Prakrit** as  **(ahaṃ)**,  **(ahaaṃ)**,  **(haṃ)**.

It is even present in some languages derivative of Maharashtri Prakrit such as: **Jain Maharastri Prakrit:  (ahai̯aṃ),  (haṃ)**

So, the question, where is it in Marathi? The accepted first person pronoun in Marathi would be **मी (Mi)**, which seems to derive from **Old Marathi  (mī)**. Where did Aham go, and where did Mi come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, some words on the Indogermanic first person singular pronoun: It is *suppletive*, this means that there are two different stems in it. The nominative is from a different stem than the oblique cases, it is *ich* in High German, *ego* in Latin and *aham* in Sanskrit. The accusative is *mich* in High German, *me* in Latin, and *mām* or *mā* in Sanskrit.

It seems that in Marathi the oblique stem also took over the nominative resulting in a simplification and regularisation of the formerly irregular paradigm.

Comment: thank you, this is a relevant and useful answer. Could you tell me some more examples in Indo Aryan languages if thats ok?

Comment: @MrJangoon — Examples: in Romani “I” (1st p. sg. pronoun) is _me_, Assamese মই (moi) and Hind: मैं (ma͠i) are both from instr. case, Sanskrit _máyā_ “by me”), Nepali म (ma), Oriya ମୁଁ (mum̐), Sinhalese මම (mama) from Sanskr. मम (mama) gen./dat. of Sanskrit अहम् (aham).

Comment: Outside Indo-Aryan languages, another parallel is Celtic, which also completely lost the nominative of the first person singular pronoun, ending up with only descendants of [Proto-Celtic _*mī_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Celtic/mī) reflected in the attested languages.